# A Measure Problem on Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm considering problem 5 on Stein's real analysis chapter 6

$X$ is a metric space, for any positive linear functional $l$ on $C_0 (X)$ which are the continuous functional on $X$ supported in some ball. There exists a unique Borel measure $\mu$ that is finite on all balls, such that $l(f)=\int f d\mu$

This is some kind of Riesz representation theorem, but metric space are not always local compact and balls are not compact, so who knows how to deal with this problem? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Uniqueness should be clear (assume the proposition and look at the difference of two such measures). The proof of existence is very similar to that of the regular Riesz theorem (note that the measure defined is indeed Borel and finite on balls, so you just need to construct a measure, and this is similar to the basic Riesz theorem).

Comment: @Moya But the original proof need local compact to ensure the partion of unity?

Comment: Actually, there are weaker conditions on topological spaces. There are certain criteria that only require paracompactness and Hausdorff. All metric spaces are paracompact and Hausdorff, so it's okay.

Comment: See here, Theorem 2.18: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~franklan/Math535_1112.pdf